# Does walk on $Z^d$ with steps $(\pm 1,\pm1,\ldots,\pm 1)$ return to origin?

Tags: pr.probability, random-walks

If the steps are iid uniform as in the title, is the return probability known? Is it positive? Answers, comments, references welcome. Clearly each of these steps is not equivalent to $d$ steps of type $\pm e_i$, especially for large $d$.

Its distribution after $n$ steps is that of $d$ independent uniform $\pm 1$ sums isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These random walks are recurrent when $d\le 2$ and transient when $d \ge 3$. That behavior happens for a wide variety of random walks.

The expected number of returns to the origin is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2^{2n}}{2n \choose n}\right)^d.$$

If the expected number of returns is $x \lt \infty$, then the probability of returning is $1-\frac{1}{x+1}$.

Mathematica evaluates the probability of returning for $d=3$ as

$$1-\frac{\Gamma(3/4)^4}{\pi}$$

but for greater $d$ the methods I tried in Mathematica left it as a particular value of a hypergeometric function which restates the series.

Comment: thanks. Bear with me, I am a bit confused, and didn't expect this to be so simple.  If $A_n$ is the event that the walk returns to the origin **at or after** step $n$ isn't the expected number of returns then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n)$? However your expression seems to be simply the sum of probabilities that the walk is at zero at each step.

Comment: @kodlu: If $A_n$ is the event that the walk first returns to the origin at or after step $n$, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty P(A_n)$ is the expected number of steps before the first return. Note that there might not be a first return. That quantity is not the same as the count of the times that the walk returns to the origin (before wandering off to infinity).